# Karate- how to check the particular word contains in json array. and how to write the contains inside json

Tags: karate

iam getting below response from api.

```
{
    "error": {
        "serverTime": 1564066755618,
        "id": "VALIDATION_EXCEPTION",
        "category": "system",
        "message": "errors: [property: username; value: ; constraint: EMAIL_INLINE_ERROR_MESSAGE_1; property: username; value: ; constraint: EMAIL_INLINE_ERROR_MESSAGE_1; property: username; value: ; constraint: EMAIL_INLINE_ERROR_MESSAGE_1"
    }
}
```

and iam checking the assertion using below way.

```
{"error":
{"serverTime":"#notnull",
"id":"VALIDATION_EXCEPTION",
"category":"system",
"message":"#notnull"
}
}
```

now I want to write a assertion for the above respose, like I want to check for field message contains the words `"EMAIL_INLINE_ERROR_MESSAGE_1"` and how many time it came.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Java interop. Then you can figure out the solution on your own. Normally no one needs this kind of validation, so it is not built in.

Please read the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate#calling-java